# create a csv file from a list with dictionary elements in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

so I have a list which has 6 dicts inside and I would like to write that to a csv file.
 I have tried a lot of ways to do it but i have been unsuccessful so far. when i try to write it as a list it give me an error when i try to write it as a dict it also give me an error. can anyone point me in the write direction please.

```
     r_vals=
     [{'distance':2.35, 'mpg': 3.215, 'power': 45.0},{'distance':214.3, 'mpg':   29.3,'power': 124.0},{'distance':2.35, 'mpg': 3.215, 'power': 45.0},...{'distance':0.35, 'mpg': 45.5, 'power': 156.0}]
```

or if there is easier way to get it as a dataframe I would like it to look like this

```
    distance   mpg       power
    2.35       3.215     45.0
    214.3      29.3      124.0
    .
    . 
    0.35       45.5      156
```

thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to get this into a CSV, and the dataframe part is just something you thought might help that goal, or are you trying to get this into a dataframe, and the CSV part is something you thought might help _that_ goal?

Comment: @roippi: For a flat list of fixed-structure dicts, I think CSV makes more sense than JSON. (It makes that fixed structure explicit, avoids repetition, gives you a more human-readable/editable file, and lets you import it into Excel.) But it was definitely worth bringing up the option to show that CSV isn't the only file format in the world; you probably shouldn't have deleted the comment…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into Pandas? http://pandas.pydata.org/

In pandas you can do this:

```
>>> r_vals
[{'distance': 2.35, 'power': 45.0, 'mpg': 3.215}, {'distance': 214.3, 'power': 124.0, 'mpg': 29.3}, {'distance': 2.35, 'power': 45.0, 'mpg': 3.215}, {'distance': 0.35, 'power': 156.0,'mpg': 45.5}]
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(r_vals)
>>> df
   distance     mpg  power
0      2.35   3.215     45
1    214.30  29.300    124
2      2.35   3.215     45
3      0.35  45.500    156
```

and then you can do a:

```
df.to_csv("path.csv",index=False)
```

and you have saved your dictionary in both a dataframe in memory and a csv.

If you want to use just native python, then you can do something like this:

```
import csv
outfile = open("path.csv","w")
csv_writer = csv.write(outfile)
csv_writer.writerow(header)
header = r_vals[0].keys()
for row in r_vals:
  csv_writer.writerow(str([row[col_name]) for col_name in header])
outfile.close()
```

Comment: If his main goal is to create and work with a data frame, the first half of this answer is obviously a _much_ better way to do it than creating a CSV file and trying to process it.

Comment: But for the second half… you're going through a lot of extra work to turn each dict into a sequence so you can use `writer` instead of `DictWriter`… Also, you don't need to call `str` with either `writer` or `DictWriter`.

Answer (score 3):

"create a csv file from a list with dictionary elements in python" is exactly what [`csv.DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) does:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=rvals[0].keys()).writerows(rvals)
```

(If your ultimate goal is to get some kind of data frame object, and you're just creating a CSV file because you think it's the best way to do that… then you don't have to; see Ryan G's answer for how easy `pandas` makes this.)

After this:

```
$ cat output.csv
3.215,45.0,2.35
29.3,124.0,214.3
3.215,45.0,2.35
45.5,156.0,0.35
```

Of course you probably want it to include the headers and/or put the columns in some particular order rather than whatever order the `dict` happens to have. (You don't need to do *both*, but if you don't do either one or the other, the CSV isn't very useful, because you'll have no idea which column means what…) Here's both:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames='distance mpg power'.split())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(rvals)
```

Output:

```
distance,mpg,power
2.35,3.215,45.0
214.3,29.3,124.0
2.35,3.215,45.0
0.35,45.5,156.0
```

If you want a variation on the default CSV dialect, see [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters). To get exactly your desired output, just add `, delimiter='\t'` to the `DictWriter` constructor.

Comment: @user3225439: _What_ did you try? _What_ didn't work? The output in my examples all come from running this exact code against your exact `rvals` but with the `...` removed to make it a valid list.

Answer (score 0):

use tabulate

```
r_vals=[[2.35,3.215,45.0],[214.3,29.3,124.0],[2.35, 3.215,45.0],[0.35,45.5,156.0]]

 print tabulate.tabulate(r_vals, headers=["distance","mpg", "power"])

  distance     mpg    power
----------  ------  -------
      2.35   3.215       45
    214.3   29.3        124
      2.35   3.215       45
      0.35  45.5        156
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest a third-party library, you should probably include a link, describe what it does (including what makes it better than stdlib solutions), or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting to do what you want:

```
with open(target, 'w') as f:
    f.write("distance\tmpg\tpower\n") # header
    for d in r_vals:
        f.write"{0[distance]:.2f}\t{0[mpg]:.3f}\t{0[power]:.1f}\n".format(d))
```

Here the format specification is `0` for the first argument to format, `[key]` to select the appropriate value, then `.nf` to give `n` decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter should do that, it will also write a header row based on the column order you provide.

```
with open('/home/dnfehren/windesk/test.csv','wb') as fl:
    fc = csv.DictWriter(fl, ['distance','mpg','power'])

    for rvalnum, rval in enumerate(rvals):
        if rvalnum == 0:
            fc.writeheader()
            fc.writerow(rval)
        else:
            fc.writerow(rval)
```

Comment: Why move `writeheader` into the loop (which then requires you to add `enumerate` and a check for `0`), when you can just call it before the loop (which then allows you to eliminate the loop and use `writerows` instead)?

Comment: thanks! good point - I usually add a loop counter out of habit as there could be other things that I want to track by where they occur in a list or file